# Is this limit $\lim(\frac{3y_n - x_n}{y^2_n})$ correct?

Tags: limits

I have tried to solve the following limit $$\lim\left(\frac{3y_n - x_n}{y^2_n}\right)$$ using the theorems for the limits, but I am not sure about what I am doing. Could you provide me some feedback and correct me (if I am wrong)?

We know that the limit of $x_n = 3$ and the limit of $y_n = 7$, and that all $y_n$ are non zero.

$$\lim\left(\frac{3y_n - x_n}{y^2_n}\right) = \frac{\lim(3y_n - x_n)}{\lim(y^2_n)} = \frac{3\lim(y_n) - \lim(x_n)}{\lim(y_n)\lim(y_n)} = \frac{3 \cdot 7 - 3}{49} = \frac{18}{49}$$

Is this correct? If not, where am I wrong? What can I improve?

Comment: well since your limits don't do anything crazy, this is correct. The denominator can also be rewritten $(\lim y_n)^2$ because square is a continuous functions

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ convergent, therefore

$$\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n+\lim b_n$$
and 
$$\lim(a_n\cdot  b_n)=\lim a_n\cdot \lim b_n.$$

It the case here, and thus, what you did is correct.

Comment: For exemple, ix you take $x_n=n$ and $y_n=-n$, then $$\lim (x_n+y_n)=0\neq \lim x_n +\lim y_n$$ because as you can see, $\lim x_n$ and $\lim y_n$ don't exist.

Comment: yes, you got it :-)